# After installing a Library through conda, compiling a C++ script, won't see its headers files

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, anaconda, conda

I have already compiled a Script on my Desktop Computer, but now I have to compile it on  a Server  where I don't have root access.

So I chose to install Anaconda  and work with Conda environments.

So, I'm installing a GCC 9.3 Compiler, among with a GXX 9.3  Compiler because I need the `execution` policies from C17++.

I also installed `GSL` library through `conda install gsl` and indeed, on `conda list` it appears to be:

```
gsl                       2.4                  h14c3975_4
```

so, I decided to compile the script via : `x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cpp SCRIPT_NAME -o _OUTNAME_ -lgsl` since this is the way Anaconda says to call it's compilers (said so on build log)

but I get this error:

```
mpi_final.cpp:1:10: fatal error: gsl/gsl_math.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated
```

I have managed to include `GSL` but ONLY when I install it manually. and then I have problem with other libraries, so I decided to fix anaconda environments. But I dont know how to proceed.

Any Idea on where to look?

Comment: I've never used Anaconda but are you sure that your conda package `gsl` contains headers ? 
After you built the library directly on your machine, did you copy all headers files to `/usr/include` or added headers file location to you IncludePath ?

Comment: Uhm, No I didnt. Is there a certain way to do this? Sorry I'm not very good with these.

Comment: Yes, the `gsl` package includes `lib`, `include`, and `bin` files. Likely you don't have search paths configured correctly (need to add `-I` and `-L` to point to the environment's `include` and `lib` directories, resp.). Personally, I just use Conda Forge's `compilers` package, which handles all that stuff automatically through activation scripts (and on Linux it does install v9.3.0 GCC/GXX).

Comment: @merv Wait,  I actually used a conda compiler. (I called it thourhg the long term gccx86-.. command not just gcc. Still doesnt load the libraries. Unless I add -I and L. Any way how to do this automatically?

Comment: I install the `conda-forge::compilers` library, which includes C, C++, and Fortran compilers and just works. When you activate the environment, it edits environment variables like `C_FLAGS`, `LD_LIBRARY`, etc. to include the relevant `lib` and `include` folders.

Comment: @merv Hi! Sorry for not checking S.E. yesterday.

I installed `conda-forge::comiplers` and indeed, the `gcc --version` showed 9.3 BUT when I tried to compile the file via `gcc mpi_final.cpp -o multi -lm -lstdc++ -std=c++17  -lpthread -ltbb -lgsl`  it prints `gsl/gsl_math.h: No such file or directory`. On the other hand the command `conda list|grep gsl` shows that `gsl 2.4` is installed on the running envrioment.  
Am I missing something?

Comment: @merv Also `which gsl-config` shows: `~/anaconda3/envs/cpp/bin/gsl-config`

Comment: Not sure why it wouldn’t work. I’d maybe check to verify that relevant environment variables are getting updated when activating the environment (e.g., run `env` before and after, looking for C_FLAGS).

Comment: @merv I run env but i dont know what to check on the log?

Comment: `grep -E '(C|CXX|LD)FLAGS'`